# Power Pivot - how to unpivot multiple colums, common months

Tags: excel, pivot, powerquery, powerpivot, unpivot

I have some data in the following format

| Item | Spend Month 1 | Spend Month 2 | Income Month 1 | Income Month 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | Number | Number | Number |
| Second | row | Number | Number | Number |

I would like to trans form this to

| Item | Month | Spend | Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | Month 1 | Number | Number |
| First | Month 2 | Number | Number |
| Second | Month 1 | Number | Number |
| Second | Month 2 | Number | Number |

Comment: @horseyride would love to answer this )))

Comment: @horseyride was asleep

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution in PowerQuery:

```
let
Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
UnpivotOtherColumns = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Quelle, {"Item"}, "Month", "Wert"),
DuplicateColumn = Table.DuplicateColumn(UnpivotOtherColumns, "Month", "Attribute"),
TextAfterDelim = Table.TransformColumns(DuplicateColumn, {{"Month", each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, " ", {1, RelativePosition.FromEnd}), type text}}),
TextBeforeDelim = Table.TransformColumns(TextAfterDelim, {{"Attribute", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, " "), type text}}),
PivotColumn = Table.Pivot(TextBeforeDelim, List.Distinct(TextBeforeDelim[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Wert")
in
PivotColumn
```

[image]